# Integration question: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(ap+bp^3+cp^5)}d{p}$

Tags: integration

My question is:how to integrate this or is this integration possible to solve?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(ap+bp^3+cp^5)}d{p}$$
My attemption using Mathematica to solve this has failed.Is anyone can solve this?

BTW, the original problem was 
$$\begin{align}&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i p x} e^{\frac{i \left(-32 E \mu  p+\frac{p^5}{5}+\frac{16 p^3}{3}\right)}{32 \lambda  \mu  \hbar }}dp\\
=&\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{\left(\frac{i \left(-80 E p+\frac{p^5}{5}+\frac{16 p^3}{3}\right)}{40 \pi }+i p x\right)} \, dp\;\;\;\text{(with real physical parameter)}\end{align}$$
I simplified it to the expression above.

If $c=0$, the result would be an Airy function.

Comment: If $c=0$, the result would be a Airy function. But the real problem is $c\neq0$.

Comment: But an additional $p^4$ term will ruin it, making it harder to solve.